# What does "spit it back out" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of the expression, “she'd spit it back out”, in the following sentence?

> That's how Jenny handled language; if she didn't understand it, she'd spit it back out
>
> <sub>[*So You Want to be a Special Education Teacher?*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=e3mNrdo8esQC&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=%22Jenny%20handled%20language%22%20%22she%27d%20spit%20it%20back%20out%22&source=bl&ots=bw1h0nH8aY&sig=OnhmIrXa9C73jGzV3p6uOCZGfv0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjApd7yr5nNAhXKliwKHUqYCt8Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Jenny%20handled%20language%22%20%22she%27d%20spit%20it%20back%20out%22&f=false)</sub>

I also came across this expression on YouTube. A boy was telling how he learnt a language “... so I listen to a lot of rap music, I memorize lyrics, I'd spit them back out...”

Comment: Could you please provide the context, or cite the source where you saw this expression? It would be helpful towards future visitors, and you'll get +1 from me if you do!

Comment: "That's how Jenny handled language; if she didn't understand it, she'd spit it back out."  Actually, I came across this expression on youtube. A boy was telling how he learnt a language "... so I listen to a lot of rap music, I memorize lyrics, I'd spit them back out..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sense here is that she repeated exactly what she'd heard without understanding and without modification.